# Error compiling wxWidgets 64 bit

Tags: c++, compilation, 64-bit, mingw, wxwidgets

I am trying to compile wxWidgets 2.8.12 with MinGW (64 bit version) on a Windows 7 64 bit machine.

To this purpose I have follow these steps http://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite-3.0.0-BETA/mingw64_how_to.html but when I do the make install-strip I get this error:

> c:\MinGW64\bin\x86_64-w64-mingw32-strip.exe:
>   'C:/msys64/local/lib/wxmsw28u_gcc_custom.dll': No such file make: ***
>   [install-strip] Error 1

Also, I have not found the lines in the wx-config that the tutorial says to change.

I get this response when I do the /configure http://pastebin.com/kcNcyNwF

What I'm doing bad? What Can I do to compile wxWidgets on 64 bit?

Answer (score 1):

If possible, use wxWidgets 2.9 as 2.8 branch had been released long time ago and I'm not sure about the status of 64 bit support there. E.g. `wx-config` should work out of the box with 2.9.

If you do need to use 2.8, then I think you can just ignore the error when stripping but check that plain `make install` worked, i.e. installed libraries and headers at the appropriate places. You can always run strip on them manually if really wanted.

Comment: I've tried to compile the 2.9 version with the /configure options like tutorial says, but it fail. Then I tried to compile with these /configure options and it compiled:
`/configure --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --disable-shared --disable-debug --disable-threads --enable-monolithic --enable-unicode`
I am using CodeBlock IDE 12.11 version and when I want to create a project with the library CodeBlocks says "Warning: A matching Release configuration cannot be found in the wxWidgets directory you specified.This means that Release target of your project will not build.Do you have any clue to fix it?